# Unable to establish a connection between a java server and an android client

Tags: java, android, connection, client-server, communication

I'm trying to build a communication application between a java server setup on a computer, and an android client setup on a smartphone, using a local network.
The problem is in the constructor of the client Socket, I passed the server IP address though no connection was established.
Here are the two files for more details:

Server.java

```
public class Server extends JFrame {
private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

//constructor
public Server(){
    super("Networking Test");
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                    userText.setText("");

                }
            }
            );
    add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
    setSize(300,150);
    setVisible(true);
}//constructor end

//setup and run the server
public void startRunning(){
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(9999);

            try{
                waitForConnection();

                setupStreams();

                whileChatting();

            }catch(EOFException eofException){
                showMessage("\n Server ended the connection!");
            }catch(StreamCorruptedException sce){
                sce.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{
                closeResources();
            }

    }catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}//startRunning() end

//wait for connection, then display connection information.
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    showMessage("Waiting for the client...\n");
    connection = server.accept(); 
    showMessage(" Now connected");

}

//get stream to send and receive data 
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");
}

//during the conversation
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    String message = " You are now connected! ";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);



    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n"+message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            showMessage("\n ERROR: Failed sending the message!");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

//close streams and sockets
private void closeResources(){
    showMessage("\n Closing connection...\n");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//send a message to the client
        private void sendMessage(String message){
            try{
                output.writeObject("SERVER - "+message);
                output.flush();
                showMessage("\nSERVER - "+message);
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                chatWindow.append("\n EROOR: Failed sending the message!  ");
            }
        }

        //update chatWindow
        private void showMessage(final String text){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            chatWindow.append(text);


                        }
                    }
                    );
        }


        //permission to type
        private void ableToType(final boolean permission){
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            userText.setEditable(permission);
                        }
                    }
                    );
        }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String message = "";
private Socket connection;
ObjectOutputStream output;
private Button send;
private EditText userText;

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    isNetworkAvailable();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+isNetworkAvailable(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//for verification purposes
    new Thread (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                //checkForConnection();

                init();
                listen();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            finally{
                //closeResources();
            }

        }
    }).start();


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

//init()
private void init() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    userText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userText);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    connection = new Socket("192.168.43.178", 9999);//this is where the 
//problem is located, that is the correct IP but the connection never starts
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
}

//listen()
private void listen(){



            send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    message = userText.getText().toString();
                    userText.setText("");
                    sendMessage(message);

                }
            });

}

//sendCommands
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject("CLIENT - "+message);
        output.flush();
    }catch(StreamCorruptedException sce){

    }catch(IOException ioe){

    }
}

//closeResources
private void closeResources(){
    try{
    output.close();
    connection.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){

    }
}

//check for connection
private void checkForConnection() throws IOException{
    ConnectivityManager check = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] info = check.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i<info.length; i++){
           if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
              Toast.makeText(this, "Connection to the internet is established", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();//other version
           }
        }


}

}
```

As for the manifest file, these are the permissions added:
     ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
     ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
     CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
     INTERNET
     CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the firewall on your server, as Java runtime creates additional processes to run your app and you may not have authorized all of them to allow through the firewall.

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten to share the manifest file, but all required permissions are already added:

Comment: Yeah, just a guess, (but that is usually it). So, please post stack trace of error you are getting

Comment: There's no error, the client just can't locate the server.

Comment: I see. Do you have a firewall running on the server? Are you on the same wifi network so that the 192.x.x.x address works? Can you connect from any other client to start to isolate where the problem is?

Comment: Yes I do have a firewall running, but the java is made an exception so it can freely connect.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. In the firwall authorized applications, there are two Java platform binary apps authorized, and another two apps blocked. When I authorized the four, it worked.

Comment: OK I updated my answer, if you would like to accept it, as it may help others in the future.